# Ensemble machine learning model with NNETAR and BRNN

Tags: r, neural-network, forecast, ensemble-learning

I used the `forecast` package to forecast the daily time-series of variable `Y` using its lag values and a time series of an external parameter `X`. I found `nnetar` model (a NARX model) was the best in terms of overall performance. However, I was not able to get the prediction of peaks of the time series well despite my various attempts with parameter tuning.

I then extracted the peak values (above a threshold) of `Y` (and of course this is not a regular time series anymore) and corresponding `X` values and tried to fit a regression model (note: not an autoregression model) using various models in `carat` package. I found out the prediction of peak values using `brnn`(Bidirectional recurrent neural networks) model just using `X` values is better than that of  `nnetar` which uses both lag values and X values.

Now my question is how do I go from here to create ensamples of these two models (i.e whenever the prediction using `brnn` regression model ( or any other regression model) is better I want to replace the prediction using `nnetar` and move forward - I am mostly concerned about the peaks)? Is this a commonly used approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to pick one model that would be the superior at anytime, it's typically better to do an average of the models, in order to include as many individual views as possible.
In the experiments I've been involved in, where we tried to pick one model that would outperform, based on historical performance, it's typically shown that a simple average was as good or better. Which is in line with the typical results on this problem: https://otexts.com/fpp2/combinations.html

So, before you try to go more advanced at it by using trying to pick a specific model based on previous performance, or by using an weighted average, consider doing a simple average of the two models.

If you want to continue with a sort of selection/weighted averaging, try to have a look at the FFORMA package in R: https://github.com/pmontman/fforma
I've not tried the specific package (yet), but have seen promising results in my test using the original m4metalearning package.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the forecast combination. I somehow overlooked this section of the e-book. I will try with simple averaging first.

FFORMA package does sound very promising. But if I figured that Model 2's prediction is always better than model 1 above a certain threshold, I could just Model 2 above the threshold and use Model 1 or simple averaging below the threshold. Although it does sound simple thing, I don't think I can archive this using FFORMA package as it does not provide an option to define models based on a threshold. 
What do you think?

Comment: I believe the FFORMA is only for weighting each of the models based on the meta learner, I'm not aware that it contains any features to perform what you describe. I believe you will need to make that logic yourself - haven't seen that case implemented.